# How to change minimum session duration value in Firebase Analytics for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm using Firebase Analytics for my iOS app. Recently I noticed that the number of daily active users in the app significantly differs from user activity in the database. It seems that Firebase identifies a session only if it's at least 10 seconds, but most of the users open the app to check the main screen for less than 10 seconds. I'm trying to find a way to set the minimum session duration value, but can't seem to find it. Is there a way to make Firebase Analytics pick the users who have short sessions as daily active users?

Android version of the SDK has a function called setMinimumSessionDuration that allows changing the default value, but the iOS version seems to be missing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found a better solution

```
// Sets the minimum engagement time in seconds required to start a new session
 [[FIRAnalyticsConfiguration sharedInstance] setMinimumSessionInterval: 1];
```

P.S you need to import `FIRAnalyticsConfiguration` class should be accessible first.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into same problem. This is what i found so far. (A hackish solution)

```
//After calling [FIRApp configure];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kFIRAnalyticsConfigurationSetMinimumSessionIntervalNotification
                                                    object:self
                                                  userInfo:@{kFIRAnalyticsConfigurationSetMinimumSessionIntervalNotification : @(1)}];
```

The above notification constant is from `FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.h`
You will need to import this file.